# Differentiating between standing waves (stationary waves) and progressive waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, waves

The question is ''Differentiate between standing waves (stationary waves) and progressive waves?"

I do not understand what exactly they would like to hear.

Should we talk about the frequency, properties, etc?

How can I incorporate their definitions into the answer? How do I pinpoint exactly what is different, beween standing waves and progressive waves?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems very much like a homework question to me, but this link http://www.s-cool.co.uk/a-level/physics/progressive-waves/revise-it/standing-waves  should, hopefully, help you to answer it yourself.

Comment: Have you considered asking your professor/instructor for clarification? Otherwise, it's really a guessing game for us to tell you what to do.

Comment: Acid Jazz,thank you for the link!I've been looking for something similar and just couldn't find it.I do understand that this is a homework question, I am new here and am just getting the hang of how to ask questions.I did need help though as my textbook doesn't provide nearly enough information,and it is currently still summer where I am and so it is very difficult to get in contact with my professors or others at my school that could help clarify. Thanks again!  Kyle,I think what they are looking for is the difference in terms of amplitude,wavelength,frequency,phase, etc.Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First advice: never seek answers to please what you believe your teachers want to hear. Doing so really limits your understanding and what you ultimately learn.

Waves are fundamentally the means by which nature expresses the movement of energy through time and space. Traveling waves are those that begin at some source of energy and can be observed a distance away from that source through what we classify as wave properties: frequency, speed and amplitude. When two waves of the same properties cross one another they can interfere resulting in what's called a 'standing' wave. Although the standing wave appears to be stationary in space it's actually the result of traveling waves interfering with one another. Standing waves and the interfering waves that create them normally occur when energy is trapped within a cavity that allows reflection of the traveling waves, such as within the length of a tube, for example. The standing wave within the cavity is essentially a resonance of the cavity. Musically instruments such as the flute are one example of such a cavity in which standing waves exist.

Comment: Thank you so much, both for your advice and clarification. I agree with you, answering to please teachers/exam criteria really does limit your understanding on what could have been an otherwise well understood topic. Just one thing though- you said that basically, standing waves are a result of traveling waves colliding, yes? Excuse my lack of knowledge here, but are those traveling waves themselves progressive?

Comment: A standing wave is possible when waves **interfere**. And yes the waves that lead to the standing wave are progressive (traveling) waves - with energy that is moving through the medium in the direction of the wave. In resonance you have energy continuously flowing between potential and kinetic states - the same is happening at any fixed location of space within the standing wave. It's just the sum of the energy in the two incoming waves. A cavity provides the ability for waves to reflect at boundaries and thus return to a point where they can interfere.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting your time into this! Much clearer now.